# Twitter Fabric or unofficial Twitter4j?

Tags: android, twitter

i'm trying to implement twitter into my app and i just want to **share** with **deep-link**.

So there should be no `login` required.

To do so i followed the `Twitter-Developer-Docs` to integrate the SDK:

https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/integrate

And they guide me to https://fabric.io/login?redirect_url=%2Fdownloads to download the IDE plugin,

but is this really what i need? Is it completely free? I don't completely understand why i need to confirm a new registration if I already have a Twitter-Account with my application set up.

Or is it better to use to unofficial `Twitter4j-libary` to fit my needs?

I think with both i can programmatically add the share-function into my app.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Twitter fabric is completely free and it is the new way of handling Twitter API. It is just like using Facebook SDK and working it without SDK . And YES you can Tweet with Twitter Fabric as well as 4j

Comment: @AvinashChowdary better late than never! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fabric and Twitter4J both have share function.

Twitter4J is better in terms of byte size. It is lightweight.
But Twitter4J has only Java methods. It doesn't have any UI components. So you have to implement share page by yourself.

On the other hand, Fabric has useful UI components like share, login, tweets list or so. In addition, it supports single sign on function.

If you want to implement only share function, I think Twitter4J is better.

Thanks.